# Is there a way to access DELL XPS media buttons programmatically

Tags: hardware

If you have seen a Dell XPS in actions you probably have noticed its nice media buttons above the normal keyboard:

[alt text http://blog.evolvedsoftwarestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/img-1397.jpg](http://blog.evolvedsoftwarestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/img-1397.jpg)

They are flashing when the notebook is starting and when you touch them.

Does anybody know how to make these buttons flash programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I had an old IBM laptop that had a keyboard light LED mounted in the top of the LCD frame (where the iSight is on a MacBook or MacBook Pro). I found that I could access this light via `/proc/acpi` under Linux.

I wrote a simple script that flashed the light on and off by interacting with /proc. There's a [posting on my blog with the code](http://lambie.org/2005/07/07/flasher/).

You might want to try running an Ubuntu live CD and seeing if it detects the buttons, and if you can access them via `/proc`. A quick search showed that the newer XPS systems work out of the box with Ubuntu, so it'd be a good starting point.